# Using Data from Firestore Data Class in reusable picker SwiftUI

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, picker

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious and I can't seem to figure it out. I want to use a reusable picker in SwiftUI, the one I am referring to is Stewart Lynch's "Reusable-Custom-Picker" https://github.com/StewartLynch/Reusable-Custom-Picker-for-SwiftUI

I have tried multiple times to get the filter working with my Firestore data and I am able to get the picker to read the data but then I am unable to filter it.

and the reusable picker struct is

```
import Combine
import Firebase
import SwiftUI

struct CustomPickerView: View {

    
    @ObservedObject var schoolData = SchoolDataStore()
    
    var datas : SchoolDataStore
    
    var items : [String]
    @State private var filteredItems: [String] = []
    @State private var filterString: String = ""
    @State private var frameHeight: CGFloat = 400
    @Binding var pickerField: String
    @Binding var presentPicker: Bool

    var body: some View {
        let filterBinding = Binding<String> (
            get: { filterString },
            set: {
                filterString = $0
                if filterString != "" {
                    filteredItems = items.filter{$0.lowercased().contains(filterString.lowercased())}
                } else {
                    filteredItems = items
                }
                setHeight()
            }
        )
        return ZStack {
            Color.black.opacity(0.4)
            VStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                presentPicker = false
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text("Cancel")
                        }
                        .padding(10)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .background(Color(UIColor.darkGray))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text("Tap an entry to select it")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .padding(.leading,10)
                    TextField("Filter by entering text", text: filterBinding)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding()
                    List {
                        ForEach(schoolData.datas, id: \.id) { i in
                                                   Button(action: {
                                                       pickerField = i.name
                                                       withAnimation {
                                                           presentPicker = false
                                                       }
                                                   }) {
                                                       Text(i.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .frame(maxWidth: 400)
                .padding(.horizontal,10)
                .frame(height: frameHeight)
                .padding(.top, 40)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onAppear {
            filteredItems = items
            setHeight()
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func setHeight() {
        withAnimation {
            if filteredItems.count > 5 {
                frameHeight = 400
            } else if filteredItems.count == 0 {
                frameHeight = 130
            } else {
                frameHeight = CGFloat(filteredItems.count * 45 + 130)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct CustomPickerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let sampleData = ["Milk", "Apples", "Sugar", "Eggs", "Oranges", "Potatoes", "Corn", "Bread"].sorted()
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomPickerView(datas: SchoolDataStore(), items: sampleData, pickerField: .constant(""), presentPicker: .constant(true))
    }
}


class SchoolDataStore : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var datas = [schoolName]()
    
    init() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("School Name").addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
            
            if err != nil{
                
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            for i in snap!.documentChanges{
                
                let id = i.document.documentID
                let name = i.document.get("Name") as? String ?? ""
                
                self.datas.append(schoolName(id: id, name: name))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct schoolName : Identifiable, Codable {
    
    var id : String
    var name : String
}
```

I have managed to get the data from Firestore into my picker now, but I am currently unable to filter.

When I change the values of the filteredItems into schoolData.datas I get an error about converting to string or .filter is not a member etc.

Anybody able to point me in the right direction with this please?

Kindest Regards,

Comment: In `CustomPickerView` are you sure you want/need `@Binding var data : [SchoolDataStore]` 
rather than `@ObservedObject var data : SchoolDataStore`. Seems to be strange to pass an array of ObservableObjects as a binding.

Comment: I had originally used an @ObservedObject, but had forgotten to change it back before posting.

Edited to reflect change. Thank you.